# Combine 3 different spark datasets into one with almost same columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have 3 different datasets: A, B and C.
Each of them have around 40 columns, all are same except the last one which is something like `a_col`, `b_col`, `c_col`.

I want to join these datasets and get a result something like:

All the 39 columns + `a_col`, `b_col`, `c_col` (without duplicating the columns)

Comment: What kind of "combine" are you after? Horizontal or vertical?

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = a.select("join_column","a_col")
val b = b.select("join_column","b_col")
val c = c.select("join_column","c_col")


val output = a.join(b,Seq("join_column")).join(c,Seq("join_column"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the list of all common columns between the dataframes to `join` them together. Small example using three dataframes where the last columns are different:

```
val dfA = Range(1,5).map(v => (v, v * 2, v * 5)).toDF("col1", "col2", "colA")
val dfB = Range(1,5).map(v => (v, v * 2, v * 6)).toDF("col1", "col2", "colB")
val dfC = Range(1,5).map(v => (v, v * 2, v * 7)).toDF("col1", "col2", "colC")

val commonCols = dfA.columns diff Seq("colA")

val df = dfA.join(dfB, commonCols).join(dfC, commonCols)
```

`df.show()` will give you:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|colA|colB|colC|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   5|   6|   7|
|   2|   4|  10|  12|  14|
|   3|   6|  15|  18|  21|
|   4|   8|  20|  24|  28|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```